# Display 12 months of data from the past 5 years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently creating a script that will pull 5 years of invoice data and will summarize the invoice amounts by month of that year for a specific customer. Example

```
Year  jan  feb mar 
2011  800  900 700
2012  700  800 900, and so forth
```

I am having issues getting my output to be like this though. My current code

```
    select MAX(cust) as customer,year(invoicedate) as y, month(invoicedate) as    m, sum(amount) as summary
          from #tquery   
          group by year(dinvoice), month(dinvoice)
          having MAX(ccustno) ='WILLAMETTE'
          order by y asc,m asc

          select * from #tquery
```

gives me this. which i just need to find a way to reformat it.

```
customer    year   month  amount
WILLAMETTE  2012    11     500
WILLAMETTE  2012    12     600
WILLAMETTE  2013    1     600
```

Comment: your query is ok. Now check for [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Search for "SQL Server PIVOT", there should be a ton of examples.

Comment: check out this simple example for Pivot. It is similar to yours, except the output is per day of week (Sat, Sun, Mon., etc): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/

Answer (score 1):

No need to go through a Pivot.  It is only 12 columns.  A conditional aggregation would be more efficient

```
 Select Customer = cust
       ,Year     = year(invoicedate) 
       ,Jan      = sum(case when  month(invoicedate) = 1 then amount else 0 end)
       ,Feb      = sum(case when  month(invoicedate) = 2 then amount else 0 end)
       ...
       ,Dec      = sum(case when  month(invoicedate) =12 then amount else 0 end)
 From  #tquery   
 Group by ccustno,year(dinvoice)
 Order By 1,2
```

Comment: **(1)** Why using non standard column aliasing? **(2)** SQL as you know is a declarative language. PIVOT is a match better fit from this perspective. **(3)**  How do you came to a conclusion that conditional aggregation has better performance than PIVOT? have you tested it by any chance?

Comment: 1) It works and and offers a better visualization. As developers, we deal with objects and abstracts.  The object in this case is JAN, not how were got there.   2) I firmly disagree.   3) Yes, but not in this particular case.  For example, one of my clients has a 5.2B row DWH, and the conditional aggregation was far superior,   Items 1 and 2 purely subjective and I don't think it warrants a DownVote.  #3 Conditional Aggregation offers a bit more flexibility (i.e additional columns/aggregates).

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: At least in SQL Server `PIVOT` is just a simplified syntax for a conditional aggregation using CASE (see http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-clause-and-pivot), but CASE is much more flexible.

Comment: @dnoeth, and `x in (1,2,3,4,5)` is just a simplified syntax for `(x=1 or x=2 or x=3 or x=4 or x=5)` but `or` is much more flexible. When did you use `OR` for this task for the last time? ... and `having` is just a simplified syntax for `select ... from (select ... group by ...) where ...` and `qualify`  is just a simplified syntax for `select ... from (select ... over () ...) where ...' and `over (... ignore nulls)` is just .... get my point? :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Of course, but hey, you usually care about portability :-), `IN` & `HAVING` is supported by every DBMS (unfortunately not `QUALIFY`). When I need to pivot there's a high probabilitiy that I have to add another aggregate (e.g. the Sum for the year or a Count in the above Select) and Pivot fails on that (it's a simplified subset of the syntax, like `COALESCE` vs. `CASE`). Agreed that it's usually more text, but it's mainly cut&paste (and don't forget to modify)

Comment: @dnoeth, I actually don't believe in portability :-) even if the syntax is identical in both databases, it says anything about the execution plans and doesn't even guarantee identical results (!), e.g. `over (order by...)` that implies  `rows unbounded preceding` is Oracle, SQL Server and PostgresSQL, have no impact in Teradata.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, the DownVote was given due to the statement “A conditional aggregation would be more efficient”. This is exactly how performance myths are created ("I once caught a fish THIS big" is not a proof )

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I understand we all have our own dogmas, but I stand by my comment "more efficient".  Just for fun, I ran some comparison tests on my Treasury Yield Rates (daily data from 1990, or about 7,000 rows).  Now, please trust me when I say I was prepared to admit that I was wrong.  Both approaches have identical execution plans (Scan 49,Hash 43, sort 8).  However execution times for conditional where 124,109,93,109,125 or an avg of 112 while the pivots where 218,171,218,170,221 or an avg of 199.6.   For such a long awaited feature, it offers virtually no value being so limited.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti. You see where my problem is? I also did some tests. I've used LocalDB 2016. I've created small sets of 1M records. for each set (and again, all of them contained 1M records) I've generated different number of customers. For our queries, some sets showed the same execution plan. Some sets showed the same execution plan but with different costs. Some sets returned different execution plans. For the first set I've created and actually tested, UNPIVOT showed better metrics. I don't know about you but I definitly can't say anything on performance at this point,

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, and here are some questions trying to explain the differences: database version? OS version? Data Volume? Size of allocated hash table? Server resources? Database setup? Statistics?

Comment: @dnoeth, This is why I love discussing this stuff. I wanted to verify something about analytic functions and got some strange results. Apparently, for Oracle, SQL Server and PostgresSQL, `over (order by ...)` implies `**range** unbounded preceding`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Well, if nothing else, we can agree that UNPIVOT is indeed superior.  Regarding your last comment... interesting.  I'll need to investigate further.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, don't get me wrong, I think that syntax wise, PIVOT is a better choice in some use-cases (until find guilty,performence wise)  but let say I'm not a big fan of the implicit aggregation it involves.The concept of "aggregate by any column that is not part of the pivot clause" should have never left the drawing board.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`  as default is based on Standard SQL, but all vendors will tell you to better use `RANGE` instead (if it returns the result you need) because it's way more efficient to calculate in most cases. I prefer not to depend on the defaults because you have to know/remember them.

Answer (score 0):

You must using `PIVOT` to reformat rows to column

Answer (score 0):

```
select      customer
           ,y
           ,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"

from       (select      cust as customer,year(invoicedate) as y, month(invoicedate) as m,amount
            from        #tquery   
            where       ccustno ='WILLAMETTE'
            )
            t

            pivot (sum (amount) for m  in ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")) p

order by    y
;
```

Comment: @mfoehrer, does it answer your question?